# C# GridViews - Make the cells in one column link to another page when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, cell

I have a grid view which is populated from a database.

I need to make it so that each of the cells in a particular column, when clicked will link through to a second page and pass the cell's text value as a query string (ie link to http://mysite.com/page.aspx?CellText='blah blah blah'). Sounds simple I know but I just can't figure it out!

This is what my page looks like at the moment:

```
<asp:GridView id="gdvTargets" 
          runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
          OnRowEditing="gdvTargets_RowEdit"
          OnRowUpdating="gdvTargets_RowUpdating" 
          OnRowUpdated="gdvTargets_RowUpdated" 
          OnRowCancelingEdit="gdvTargets_RowCancelingEdit"

          cssClass="grid"
          >
<HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader"></HeaderStyle>
```

And my c# code behind it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
year = Request.QueryString["YearSelector"];
targetType = Request.QueryString["TargetType"];

      gdvTargets.DataSource = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable("EXEC sp_getTargets " + year + ", " + targetType).Return;
      gdvTargets.DataBind();

    }
```

This results in a table which looks something like this:

```
ID        System        Target 1       Target 2       Target3       Target 4
0         ALL           10             20             15             10
2         Machine1      4              7              7              7
5         Xfgb 45       6              13             8              3
```

I would like the system column to be clickable and link through to a new page but take the name of the system with it. Hope this makes sense! Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<a href=''>" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "</a>";
}
```

Replace 0 by your column index

Comment: You're a beautiful man! This is what I was looking for thankyou. With a little bit of tweaking it has also solved another problem I was having :) Merci

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnRowCommand` event. In your markup, set up a `TemplateField` with a `LinkButton`, and set the `CommandName` and `CommandArguments` of the link button to the necessary information. I.e., you can name the `CommandName` "link" (or whatever you wish) and the `CommandArgument` the id of a table row, or the url to the page, etc.

When the row command event is fired, check what command it is and do what you wish inside of that.

```
public void gridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Link")
    {
        int key = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        Response.Redirect(string.Format(
            "http://mySite/index.aspx?id={0}", key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dave! 
I forgot to mention that all the cells are editable except from the System column. I need to make only the cells in this column link through.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HyperLinkField` to your `Gridview` and set the following properties:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="System" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="page.aspx?CellText={0}" 
                    DataTextField="System" />
```

`DataTextField` : Text to Display in the Column
  `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` : Url to Navigate along query string with 0 index
  `DataNavigateUrlFields` : Fields to pass in the query string. if you want to pass more than 1 field, separate it by commas.